# How to figure out which Atlas map bonus objective is not complete yet?

Tags: path-of-exile

How to figure out which Atlas map bonus objective is not complete yet?[image: Atlas map]

Answer (score 5):

- **1:  Look at the atlas.**  The one you haven't completed is the one in the top right that's still grayed out (rather than being highlighted with a golden circle around it).  So in your case, the missing map is **[Port](https://www.poewiki.net/wiki/Map:Port_Map_(Archnemesis))**.  If you'd completed the map but not with the bonus objective, it would be highlighted, but without the golden circle.
- **2:  Use the map stash tab.**  Mousing over the subtab for each map in your map stash tab will tell you whether you have completed each map (and its bonus objective).  This text will appear in green if you have completed them, and red if not, so it's fairly easy to see at a glance which one is missing (unless, of course, you are red-green colorblind).  Obviously this option is only available to you if you have purchased the map stash tab.